# Javascript Relational Operator Showing Weird Behavior with Strings

Tags: javascript

Why Javascript relational operator showing weird result when comparing three strings? Am i wrong or Javascript got buggy?

```
var number1 = 1
var number2 = 1
var number3 = 1
number1 == number2 //true
number1 == number3 //true
number2 == number3 //true
number1 == number2 == number3 //true. Good!
```

Now the problemetic part:

```
var string1 = "a"
var string2 = "a"
var string3 = "a"
string1 == string2 //true
string2 == string3 //true
string1 == string3 //true
```

Why the following gives false?

```
string1 == string2 == string3 //false.  WHY IS THAT??
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
string1 == string2 == string3
```

means:

```
(string1 == string2) == string3
```

which is to say:

```
true == string3
```

That's not `true`, so it's `false`.

If you want to see if the three strings are all the same, you need

```
string1 == string2 && string2 == string3
```

*edit* — it all has to do with the type conversion implicit in the behavior of the `==` operator, along with the syntax of expressions and the rules of operator precedence. The `==` operator is *left associative*, which means that a string of `==` expressions as in this question is treated with left-weighted parentheses (as shown above in my answer).

To break things down, after the first comparison you've got

```
true == string3
```

So there's a boolean on the left side and a string on the right. The rules of the `==` operator say that in that case, you treat the comparison as a comparison between the *numeric* value of the boolean and the other operand, which gives

```
1 == string3
```

Now we've got a number and a string. In *that* case, the rules for `==` say to convert the string to a number, which gives

```
1 == NaN
```

when `string3` is `"a"`.  That comparison is between a number and another number, so it's a simple numeric equality test with the result `false`. Given all that, note that if the strings had been initialized like this:

```
var string1 = "1", string2 = "1", string3 = "1";
```

then the expression

```
string1 == string2 == string3
```

would be `true`. Similarly, and perhaps even more surprising than the result of the original test,

```
"2" == "2" == "1"
```

would be `true`!

Comment: @djechlin this is a JavaScript question, not Java

Comment: @Pointy I was thinking the same thing, but i'm wondering why it's not doing same with the numbers? this is my actual question.

Comment: It only appears to work in the case of the numbers because `1 == true` is true in Javascript.

Comment: Also note that `number1 === number2 === number3` would be `false` :)

Answer (score 2):

First, best practice in Javascript is to avoid `==` and use `===` instead.  The `==` operator tries very hard - some would say too hard - to come up with a valid way to compare its operands, so it can yield some surprising results.

In your first example, this code:

```
number1 == number2 == number3
```

is actually interpreted as this:

```
(number1 == number2) == number3
```

That is, Javascript first compares `number1` and `number2`, yielding - in this case - `true`.  It then compares the result (`true`) and `number3`... which is *also* true, because `true == 1` is a true statement in Javascript. That is, `true` has a numeric value of 1. (Note that even though *any* nonzero number evaluates as true, or at least truthy, in a Boolean context, only the number 1 tests as equal to `true` itself.)

If you use `===`, you get a different result, since `true === 1` is false.  In fact, `x === y` is always false if `x` and `y` are not the same type of value.

When you get to the strings, you can see that this is not going to work even with `==`, because `true == s` is not true for most strings `s`.  (The exception is if `s` is a string representation of the number "1", as then it is first converted to the number 1, which as we said above tests as `==` to `true`).

If you want to compare that three things are all equal to each other, you need to compare two pairs of them and AND them together:

```
if ((number1 === number2) && (number2 === number3)) {...}
```

So, to sum up: if you set `number1` and friends to 2 instead of 1, you get `false` in the first example. If you set `string1` and friends to "1" instead of "a", you get `true` in the second.  And if you use `===` instead of `==`, you avoid all the confusion.